# QThread::idealThreadCount() always returning "2"

Tags: multithreading, qt, qthread

I need to display, in a QSpinBox, the number of cores, or threads, that the CPU has. The problem is:

```
QThread cpuInfo(this); //get CPU info
ui->spnBx_nmb_nodes->setValue(cpuInfo.idealThreadCount()); //get thread count
```

This is always returning "2". I tried in a "2 cores/4 threads" notebook; a "4 cores/8 threads" computer and a "12 cores/ 24 threads" server. In all the cases, this is returning "2" as the ideal thread count.

Can someone, please, give me some light?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`idealThreadCount()`'s implementation is different on different OS's:

On Windows, `QThread::idealThreadCount()` calls the Win32 function [GetNativeSystemInfo()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724340(v=vs.85).aspx) and from its results, returns the `dwNumberOfProcessors` value from the `SYSTEM_INFO` struct that call populates.

On Linux (and most other Unix-y OS)'s, `QThread::idealThreadCount()` calls [sysconf(_SC_NPROCESSORS_ONLN)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/sysconf.3.html) and returns that value.

On MacOS/X (and BSD and iOS), `QThread::idealThreadCount()` calls [sysctl(CTL_HW, HW_NCPU)](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?sysctl(8)) and returns the value it receives from there.

`QThread::idealThreadCount()` also contains some other back-end implementations for less-commonly used OS's, which I won't attempt to summarize here; if you need to look for yourself, the code is at [lines 461-515 of `qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/thread/qthread_unix.cpp.html#_ZN7QThread16idealThreadCountEv).

Given all of the above, the question devolves to, why is the OS-command (that Qt is calling through to) returning 2 instead of a more appropriate number?  It sounds like a bug to me, although one other possibility is that `idealThreadCount()` is returning the correct number, but your `QSpinBox` is clamping that number down to 2 for some reason.  If you haven't done so already, I suggest printing out the value returned by `cpuInfo.idealThreadCount()` directly, in addition to passing it to `setValue()`, just to be sure.

Comment: I used `qDebug()` to check values, and `idealThreadCount()` was returning the correct value. After a little more of debugging, I had a connected slot redefining the value. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code:

```
auto const value = 8;
auto *nmb_nodes = ui->spnBx_nmb_nodes;
nmb_nodes->setValue(value);
Q_ASSERT(nmb_nodes->value() == value);
```

My bet is that the assertion will not be fulfilled. So your problem is likely not what you think it is.